# Question regarding Mean value theorem and a monotonically increasing function $f'$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

I was given the following information about a function:
Let $f$: [0,$\infty$) be a function so that

- $f(0)=0$
- $f$ is continuous on [0,$\infty$)
- $f$ is differentiable on (0,$\infty$)
- the function $f'$: [0,$\infty$) is monotonically increasing

Let $x, y \in (0, \infty)$ where $x < y$.
We know that f is differentiable on (0,x) and (0,y) as well.
By Mean Value Theorem there exists a $c \in (0, x)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}$=$\frac{f(x)}{x}$.
And, there exists a $d \in (0, y)$ such that $f'(d) = \frac{f(y) - f(0)}{y}$=$\frac{f(y)}{y}$.

I was confused with the values $c,d$ I defined, Since $x<y$ does this mean that $c<d$? I have no idea if this is true but I want to know if theres any sort of relationship between $c$ and $d$ using this function $f$?

Comment: By "monotonically increasing", do you mean *strictly increasing* or just *non-decreasing*?

Comment: You can try using $f'(d) = \frac{f(y)-f(0)}{y} = \Big(1-\frac{x}{y}\Big)\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}+\frac{x}{y}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}$. But you would need to know whether $f'$ is strictly increasing or non-decreasing.

Comment: It means non-decreasing